# ¿Cómo convertir un string en un array de bytes para luego desencriptar?

Tags: java, encriptación, rsa

El proceso de encriptación es en el sistema RSA que devuelve un array de bytes, lo convierto en string y ahora este lo quiero pasar a desencriptar. Tengo un método que desencripta el string que viene por parámetro, antes de desencriptarlo intento convertirlo de nuevo a un array de bytes pero me devuelve un error y no sé cual sea la razón

El error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid encoded ciphertext
    at encriptadores.RSA.desencriptar(RSA.java:46)
    at encriptadores.RSA.main(RSA.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3f
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
    at encriptadores.RSA.desencriptar(RSA.java:44)
    ... 1 more
```

El main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RSA r = new RSA();
        String msjEncriptado = new String(r.encriptar("hola mundo!"), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        String msjDesencriptado = new String(r.desencriptar(msjEncriptado), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    }
```

El método:

```
public byte[] desencriptar(final String txtCifrado) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException{
        final byte[] bufferCifrado;
        byte[] bufferClaro;
        try {
            bufferCifrado = Base64.getDecoder().decode(txtCifrado);
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid encoded ciphertext", e);
        }
        //Desencriptación utilizando la clave privada
        Cipher cifrador = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cifrador.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clavePrivada);
        //Obtener y mostrar texto descifrado
        bufferClaro = cifrador.doFinal(bufferCifrado);
        return bufferClaro;
    }
```

Comment: Cipher de donde viene? es parte de bouncycastle?

Comment: No, es de la librería de Java

Comment: cual de todas las librerías?

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es porque el texto que quieres desifrar primero lo intentas decodificar con un decodificador de Base64 y al perecer este texto no tiene un formato válido de Base64, por tal motivo te lanza una `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. Esto es lo que dice la documentación de [Base64.Decoder.decode(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-)

> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if src is not in valid Base64 scheme

Asegúrate que esta expresión devuelva una cadena en Base64:

```
new String(r.encriptar("hola mundo!"), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Comment: Es verdad, todavía no encuentro como hacerlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Nacho comparte el código del método encriptar también para poder ayudarte entonces.